# What does Cordova/Phone Gap debug mode do?

Tags: cordova, meteor

My app only works in debug mode, so I am wondering what it does so hopefully I can fix the problem with my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it:

- Minifys the code
- Comepletely checks the code for errors